# Visual Basic "msgbox" and GoTo command

Tags: vbscript, msgbox, cd-drive

I would like to create a VBScript file that opens a msgbox that has the options "Yes or No" and maybe a question mark icon. I would like yes to open a specified path to a file, and no to end the program. I want the dialogue box to say: Would you like to eject the CD drive?... I have this code (cd eject) so don't need it. But I do need to figure out the code to create the message box ad to open the vbs script upon Yes. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you even try to do it yourself? All of this is easily found with a quick search here or on Google.

Comment: Yes I did. I tried the "GoTo" command, but it always ave me a runtime error, and when I tried using multiple lines (if the msgbox is 6 code &_ next line etc.) that didn't work, not did just putting the code all I one line with &s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking at the [MsgBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function here. Also, information on the [Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) function. Both have examples showing what you're asking for.

```
If MsgBox("Would you like to eject the CD drive?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
    'Code to eject the CD drive
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    objShell.Run "C:\Path\To\File.exe" 'Run normal file
    objShell.Run "wscript.exe C:\Path\to\File.vbs" 'Run VBScript
End If
```